# Autofill numbers with letter prefixes in excel

Tags: excel, vba, numbers, autofill, prefix

How do I autofill in excel when there is a prefix? Here is my code that autofills column A with user input start number and last number. But I want to modify it so that it can handle numbers with prefixes

example) start number: CAR001 end number: CAR120.

I would expect this above example to autofill column A: CAR001, CAR002, CAR003 etc to CAR120

note: prefix is not always the same

```
a = InputBox("Start number" & vbNewLine & "or 0 to exit")
If Not IsNumeric(a) Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    'a is a number and can be converted to Integer
    start_num = CInt(a)
End If
If start_num = 0 Then Exit Sub

b = InputBox("End number" & vbNewLine)
If Not IsNumeric(b) Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    'a is a number and can be converted to Integer
    last_num = CInt(b)
End If

  'start at first number
    ws.Range("A1") = start_num
    'stop at last number
    ws.Range("A1").Select
    Selection.DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Date:=xlDay, _
            Step:=1, Stop:=last_num, Trend:=False
```

Comment: Where are you getting the prefix from? The user?

Comment: Yes prefix from the user! it would be entered all in one (prefix+number in same entry)

Comment: if it fails the isNumeric test I will try to use a for loop to search for a number (0-9) in the string, then split at that value :)

Answer (score 1):

This example fill the `A` Column with the given prefix and start to end number.

```
Sub filler()
c = InputBox("Prefix" & vbNewLine & "or 0 to exit")
If c = 0 Then Exit Sub
a = Application.InputBox("Start number" & vbNewLine & "or 0 to exit", , , , , , 1)
If a = 0 Then Exit Sub
b = Application.InputBox("End number" & vbNewLine, , , , , , 1)
b = CInt(b)
Range("A1") = c & a
Range("A1").AutoFill Range("A1:A" & b - a + 1), xlFillSeries
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe `Range("A1") = c & Format(a, "000")` if user needs 3 digits.